# Unable to understand the significance of regex and inplace in pd.replace ( regex = False , inplace=False)

Tags: python, regex, pandas

[`DataFrame.replace(to_replace=None, value=None, inplace=False, limit=None, regex=False, method='pad', axis=None)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Can anyone explain the significance of regex and inplace in the above line?

Comment: You are already linking to the documentation, where the two parameters are explained. Is your question what a regex is and what inplace means in general?

Comment: inplace = True will alter the same dataframe no need to assign

Comment: I am unable to understand the explanation in the documentation itself @FlyingTeller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from doc :

> regex : bool or same types as to_replace, default False
>
> Whether to interpret to_replace and/or value as regular expressions.
>   If this is True then to_replace must be a string. Otherwise,
>   to_replace must be None because this parameter will be interpreted as
>   a regular expression or a list, dict, or array of regular expressions.
>
> inplace : boolean, default False
>
> If True, in place. Note: this will modify any other views on this
>   object (e.g. a column from a DataFrame). Returns the caller if this is
>   True.

```
In [39]: import pandas as pd

In [40]: df = pd.DataFrame({"country":["United Kingdom of Great Britain", "Ireland", "United Kingdom of Great Britain & Ireland"], "value":[12,31, 43]})

In [41]: df
Out[41]: 
                                     country  value
0            United Kingdom of Great Britain     12
1                                    Ireland     31
2  United Kingdom of Great Britain & Ireland     43
```

## passing the regex pattern ^ and * in string as parmeter`to_place` and `value` that will replace the matching pattern with value

```
In [42]: df.country.replace("^United Kingdom of Great Britain.*", "United Kingdom", regex=True, inplace=True)

In [43]: df
Out[43]: 
          country  value
0  United Kingdom     12
1         Ireland     31
2  United Kingdom     43
```

from above String "United Kingdom......." get replaced by value united kingdom and `inplace = True` modified the same dataframe `df.`

Comment: so what is regex specially doing in the above case? Why are we not using their default values?

Comment: see the pattern in string `^United Kingdom of Great Britain.*` ^ will match the start and * will match anything in last

Comment: I still did not get the regex part. Sorry to bother @Roushan.

Comment: so u know the regex pattern ? if not then consider to read https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for your help @Roushan. I understood it now.